# Is there a way to find the inverse of a regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My current regex can identify numbers that are toll free, what i'm trying to do is look up phone numbers that are not toll free. Here is my current code:

```
    if ( phoneNumbers.match(/^(\+?1)?(8(00|44|55|66|77|88)[2-9]\d{6})$/) && data.results[i].duration > 90 && data.results[i].disposition === "ANSWERED") {
        console.log(phoneNumbers);
    }
```

I have tried the following expressions:

```
/^(\+?!1)?!(8(00|44|55|66|77|88)[2-9]\d{6})$/

    if ( phoneNumbers/not().match(/^(\+?1)?(8(00|44|55|66|77|88)[2-9]\d{6})$/) && data.results[i].duration > 90 && data.results[i].disposition === "ANSWERED") {
        console.log(phoneNumbers);
    }
```

but that does not seem to work either. Is it even possible to look up the inverse of a regex?

Comment: `!phoneNumbers.match(/^(\+?1)?(8(00|44|55|66|77|88)[2-9]\d{6})$/)` or better: `!/^(\+?1)?(8(00|44|55|66|77|88)[2-9]\d{6})$/.test(phoneNumbers)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte can't believe I didnt remember that. Thanks. Drop that as your answer and I will mark it as solved. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you looking for inverse of regex or inverse of condition ? Because both are way too different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any condition you want to use in javascript can be "inversed" with `!`

```
if(condition){
   //Here you do something if the condition is true
}

if(!condition){
    //Here you do something if the condition is false
}
```

In you corde

```
if(phoneNumbers.match(/^(\+?1)?(8(00|44|55|66|77|88)[2-9]\d{6})$/)){
   //Here you have a toll free
}

if(!phoneNumbers.match(/^(\+?1)?(8(00|44|55|66|77|88)[2-9]\d{6})$/)){
    //Here you have a NO toll free
}
```

Comment: How is your answer different from @Casimir et Hippolyte's comment ?

Comment: I guess no difference aside from the explanation. If someone ask how much is 2 + 2 is rarely to get two different answer.